# Get SoapClient to always parse XML tag as an array

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm using PHP's SoapClient to load the following XML under 2 scenarios

1. In scenario A, the multiple `Sales_Order_Line` are returned as an array of `stdClass`
2. In scenario B, the single `Sales_Order_Line` is returned as a `stdClass`

The XSD schema is provided, but I'm not sure how to make SoapClient follow it.

How can I make it always return as an array even in scenario B?

Scenario A

```
<Soap:Envelope xmlns:Soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Soap:Body>
        <ReadMultiple_Result xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/salesorder">
            <ReadMultiple_Result>
                <SalesOrder>
                    ...
                    <SalesLines>
                        <Sales_Order_Line>
                        </Sales_Order_Line>

                        <Sales_Order_Line>
                        </Sales_Order_Line>

                        <Sales_Order_Line>
                        </Sales_Order_Line>
                    </SalesLines>
                </SalesOrder>
            </ReadMultiple_Result>
        </ReadMultiple_Result>
    </Soap:Body>
</Soap:Envelope>
```

Scenario B

```
<Soap:Envelope xmlns:Soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Soap:Body>
        <ReadMultiple_Result xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/salesorder">
            <ReadMultiple_Result>
                <SalesOrder>
                    ...
                    <SalesLines>
                        <Sales_Order_Line>
                        </Sales_Order_Line>
                    </SalesLines>
                </SalesOrder>
            </ReadMultiple_Result>
        </ReadMultiple_Result>
    </Soap:Body>
</Soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the response with [xpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php). It returns an array at success.

### Update for clarification

The **only one** XPath expression meets your needs in both scenarios. Let's say you've got a raw xml response `$rawResponse`. Then you can retrieve array of `Sales_Order_Line` objects with a code like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($rawResponse);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("salesorder", "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/salesorder");
$salesOrderLines = $xml->xpath("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/salesorder:ReadMultiple_Result/salesorder:ReadMultiple_Result/salesorder:SalesOrder/salesorder:SalesLines/salesorder:Sales_Order_Line");
var_dump($salesOrderLines);
```

In scenario A output will be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) {
  }
  [2]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) {
  }
}
```

In scenario B output will be:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) {
  }
}
```

### Alternative method

If you don't want to deal with the raw response, look at [SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS feature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.construct.php#soapclient.construct.options.features).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following. What I'm looking for is a way to handle this automatically instead of me having to point out in every XML which tag should always be an array. Currently, I know that info is held in the XSD, so logically, I'm looking for a way to inform the reader about it, open to any other alternatives. Thank you.

Comment: I've added an explanation. See updated answer.